# CSS media query on Nexus 5

Tags: android, html, css

i discovered some strange behaviour on my nexus 5 - or am i doing something wrong?

i use this css for a bigger font on mobile devices with small displays (or in portrait view)

```
html {
    font-size: 14px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width : 800px) {
    html{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

when loading the page in portrait view on my nexus 5, it looks just like it's supposed to: 20px font-size. now when turning the phone to landscape view it changes to 14px. so far so good.

now when turning the phone back to portrait view, the font-size stays 14px. Why that? My mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but did you set a viewport meta tag?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`